# Python package imports on Google Cloud Ubuntu server with apache and flask

Tags: python, flask, apache2, ubuntu-14.04

I have a Machine Learning application that I developed locally and run it without troubles on a server localhost:5000 on my Mac

Now going onto google cloud I have a ubuntu server where I installed apache2 and flask and run an initial python script sending me just of ping information back. OK so far.

Now, I start to import packages such as CV2, tensorflow, Keras ,... and get into troubles.
To debug I tried out interactively under Python (3.5) all imports I need and they work like a charm.

So, I thought first that I have user/group permission problems where apache cannot access some data it needs.
I added the www-data user to my group but to no avail.

Next I started with a Python file that imports only a subset of the packages so to test.

the imports it does are the ones below where it works nicely (tested with a route that just returns a ping info)

```
 from __future__ import print_function
 import tensorflow as tf
 from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile

 import time
 from datetime import datetime
 from six.moves import xrange
 from six.moves import cPickle as pickle

 import numpy as np
 import sys
 import os
 import random
 import glob
 import shutil
 import dicom
 from PIL import Image

 import scipy.misc as misc
 import scipy as sp
 from scipy import ndimage
```

when I start ask for the rest of the imports (partially shown below), it does not work any longer

```
 import skimage
 from skimage import measure
 ...
 ...
```

The apache error log does not show much. When I restarts the server it reports "resuming normal operations".

When I access a route to tell me "hello world", the request just hangs and never completes.

I am lost with my knowledge and needs some help

Thanks  a lot
Peter

Comment: Hey Peter, did it work before you started to import packages such as CV2, tensorflow?